# How to redirect between Wordpress site using .htaccess if the origin has .html

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect

How to redirect between Wordpress site using .htaccess if the origin has .html
the first site i use permalink .html example:

www.domain.com/articles/content.html

if i'd like to use 301 redirect to the new site

www.newdomain.com/content (without .html)

anyone can gie me any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use in .htaccess file:  `Redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.newdomen.com/new`
or Use RewriteEngine:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteBase     /
RewriteRule     ^articles\/(.*)\.html$  $1 [R=301]
```